# bundledoc fails with subfolder paths (MiKTeX)

Tags: errors, miktex, knitr

I would like to use bundledoc mainly in Windows with MiKTeX. However, I encounter a problem with subfolder paths that is annoying. I run the program as follows:

```
bundledoc --config=miktex.cfg paper.dep
```

and I get an error message:

> bundledoc: "ksepwhich -progname=latex %BDINPUTS%"
>   (BDINPUTS="figure/Fig1.pdf") failed to find figure/Fig1.pdf

So the program finds all the packages and the files in the current folder as listed in paper.dep file, but fails when it attempts to find the first file that is in a subfolder. The problem is that the path should be "`figure\Fig1.pdf`" not "`figure/Fig1.pdf`" as written by snapshot. Should snapshot write "`\`" instead of "`/`" as folder separator or should bundledoc be able to interpret that, I dunno.

How could I solve this?

EDIT: I produce paper.tex from paper.Rnw in R with knitr package. Alternating between "`/`" and "`\`" did not solve problem, but removing the subfolder file line from dep file helped bundledoc to do its job.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks for heads up! I'll take a look at your guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem are not the slashes/backslashes. Neither

```
ksepwhich -progname=latex figure/Fig1.pdf
```

nor

```
ksepwhich -progname=latex figure\Fig1.pdf
```

will work on miktex.

If you want to find files in subfolders one must add `./` at the begin:

```
ksepwhich -progname=latex ./figure/Fig1.pdf
ksepwhich -progname=latex .\figure\Fig1.pdf
```

will both output `./figure/Fig1.pdf`

The native miktex application findtexmf works similar

```
findtexmf -alias=pdflatex ./figure/Fig1.pdf
findtexmf -alias=pdflatex .\figure\Fig1.pdf
```

but outputs the pathes with backslashes: `.\figure\Fig1.pdf`

I don't think that the snapshot package can know the cases where an `./` before a path is needed (it would break the search in the texmf tree if it were everywhere). The bundledoc package could probably try both variants: first the value provided by snapshot and -- if this fails -- again with `./`, so you could make a feature request.

But probably the best is to enter subfolder pathes as

```
\includegraphics{./figure/Fig1.pdf}
```

Comment: You are right. I edited dep-file. First I changed / to \ which did not solve my problem. Next I deleted the lines for files in subfolders and after that everything worked except that files in figure folder where not included.

Comment: However, including \graphicspath{{./figure}} did not change subfolder notation in dep file.

Comment: `\graphicspath{{./figure/}}` (note the additional backslash) works fine for me together with `\includegraphics{Fig1}`. The dep-file contains the `./`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by including

```
opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "./figure/")
```

in paper.Rnw.